# jQuery Plugin - access method of instantiated object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know, this has been asked multiple times, but somehow, I can't find an answer that fits my needs, so here it goes.

I made a plugin which looks like this (stripped down):

```
(function(window, $){

    var MyPlugin = function(elem, options){
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;
        this.metadata = this.$elem.data('popup-options');
        this.markup = '<div>some markup here</div>';
        this.popup = null;
    };

    MyPlugin.prototype = {
        defaults:{
            type: 'outer',
            color: 'orange'
        },

        init: function(){

            this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

            this.show();

            return this;
        },

        show: function(){

            // some stuff to show the element

        },

        hide: function(){

            // some stuff to hide the element
        },


        someMethod: function(){

            // some other stuff the plugin does
        }


    };

    MyPlugin.defaults = MyPlugin.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        return this.each(function(){
            var thePlugin = new MyPlugin(this, options).init();
        });
    };

    window.MyPlugin = MyPlugin;

}(window, jQuery));
```

Now in the code I apply the plugin like this:

```
var thePlugin = $(this).myPlugin();
```

So far, this works.

But now, I wanna access one of the functions within the plugin from outside (e.g. «someMethod»).

I tried to call it like:

`thePlugin.someMethod();`

or 
`thePlugin.myPlugin.someMethod();`

or even

`thePlugin.myPlugin[0].someMethod();`

none of this works.

How do I have to make the Plugin, so I can access it after it's been initialized?
Is this possible at all?

Comment: have you tried `myPlugin.prototype.someMethod()`?

Comment: tried that, didn't work... :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I had to change the return-statement of the plugin like this:

```
$.fn.updPopup = function(options){
        return new UpdPopup(this, options).init();
};
```

This returns only a single instance of the plugin.

Then I can access it like this:

```
thePlugin.someMethod();
```

Question remains: how would I access it with the original return statement (that apparently returns an array of objects, I guess)?